# projection of $f$ onto subspace $\overline{M}$

Tags: functional-analysis

Given Hilbert space $L^2([0,1], \mathbb{R})$ and $f(t)=t^2$. Find projection of $f$ and distance $f$ onto subspace $\overline{M}$ with 
$M= \{ x \in L^2([0,1], \mathbb{R}) \mid \int_0^1 x(t)\, dt =0 \}$

I proved that $\overline{M}$ is a closed subspace so it has a projection and we have a projection formula but i can't get the orthonormal basis of $\overline{M}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hint*: Use that

$$
 M = \{ x \in L^2([0,1],\mathbb R) \mid (\mathbf 1,x)_{L^2(\Omega)} = 0 \} = \mathbf 1 ^\perp
$$

where $\mathbf 1$ is the constant function with value $1$ and $(\cdot,\cdot)_{L^2(\Omega)}$ is the scalar product in the Hilbert space.

Comment: ohhhh! thank you @supinf